# Magento 2 - Do I have to create a new theme and recode my extensions after upgrading to magento 2 enterprise?

Tags: magento2, module, theme, extensions, magento2-enterprise

Do I have to create a new theme after upgrading to magento 2 enterprise and will my extensions stop working?

Comment: What extensions ?

Comment: Custom ones, and extensions from Amasty, Aheadworks, GitHub etc.

Comment: Who knows... they should not, what magento version you are migrating to what magento enterprise edition ?

Comment: "Who knows..." Then please only answer if you have experience with both, community and enterprise and already went through the process. And why should they not?!

Comment: You wrote "custom extensions" how the hell anyone will answer that ? We don't know what is in there, thou it's not possible to answer your question ;) that's why "who knows...."

Comment: @GosuPrzmak, so you claim there is something that we can do wrong in custom extensions which renders them useless in enterprise?

Comment: I assume it can break for example if your extensions added a product type like "giftcards" and magento enteprise will want to add giftcards,